# SSRS - An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘255’

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, ssrs-2017

Since a server move, we've been experiencing issues with most of our SSRS reports when opening in Report Builder. Getting the error message:

"Failed to preview report. An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘255’."

This is on all of our existing reports and new ones created.

I've narrowed down the issue to when a built-in field, parameter or any expression is included in a text box. I can preview a report if none of those are present in the report. This occurs when running Report Builder locally or on the report server.

I've seen many solutions to this problem mentioning the version of .net being up-to-date but we are running version 4.8. We're on Report Builder 15.0.900.71, Reporting Services runs on SQL Server 2016.

Any advice from someone that's experienced similar and it not being a .net issue or if I'm missing something with .net - I'd love to hear from you!

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while trying to Deploy a report from Visual Studio to SSRS as well.  Once I was OUT of the report in my browser, I was then able to Deploy the updated report.  It appears that this error occurs when the SSRS report is in use - blocking the deployment of updates.  I hope this is the case for you as well!